# Are ERC20 token names unique?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ens

I am curious if ERC20 token names are unique on the Ethereum block chain? For example, what is to stop someone from creating a new token called Golem (GNT) and publishing it to a smart contract?

I have a hunch they are not. Is there a reason for this?

It could end up being confusing to people if token names start repeating, imagine an ERC20 token called ETH

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There could be any number of ERC20 contracts deployed with the `name` string variable "Golem Network Token." However, each one of these contracts has a unique Ethereum contract address. The ERC20 contract address deployed by Golem is [0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d](https://etherscan.io/token/Golem). If someone else deployed a clone contract it would have a different address and could be easily identified as a clone. The Golem ERC20 contract can also be easily lookedup by its [ENS](https://ens.domains/) domain, [gnt.thetoken.eth](https://etherscan.io/enslookup?q=thetoken.eth), which is managed by ENS creator, Nick Johnson.

Comment: Yes, you could confirm it. But it still presents a problem where tokens can be easily copied to confuse consumers

Comment: Imagine the NASDAQ allowed multiple companies to use the same ticker, sure you could sort out who was who. But kindof a Charlie Foxtrot

Comment: @VinnieJames, the ticker symbol in this case is the contract address, not the token name.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain doesn't care if there are hundreds of tokens with the same name and abbreviation. However, Nasdaq, in this case, is a crypto exchange and no exchange would list two tokens with the same name. So it is in the project's best interest to have a unique name that won't make confusion.

Comment: Good point, but how to I know that someone else is not publishing their contract and planning to promote the same memecoin token name as myself? If we both published around the same time and starting promoting around the same time, it becomes a game of chicken?